# Javascript: How to copy all options from one select element to another?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

How can I copy all `options` of one `select` element to another? Please give me the easiest way, I'm allergic to looping.

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe someone will find it helpful. I had a similar task, I wanted to replicate a select over all rows of a table column. I used sel1 = sel0.cloneNode(true)

Comment: Very useful, @Singagirl. Thank you! Just be aware to change the id later.

Comment: +1 for this.  Other answers didn't work to copy one Select to a new Select, without retaining links to the old one (not a true clone), or the other answers were much more than what I needed

Answer (score 31, accepted):

html:

```
<select id="selector_a">
    <option>op 1</option>
    <option>op 2</option>
</select>

<select id="selector_b">
    <option>op 3</option>
    <option>op 4</option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
var first = document.getElementById('selector_a');
var options = first.innerHTML;

var second = document.getElementById('selector_b');
var options = second.innerHTML + options;

second.innerHTML = options;
```

Answer (score 43):

One of the easiest ways without looping, is using `jquery` (`select1` = id of select 1, `select2` = id of select 2):

```
$('#select1 option').clone().appendTo('#select2');
```

Without `jquery`:

```
var select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
var select2 = document.getElementById("select2");
select2.innerHTML = select2.innerHTML+select1.innerHTML;
```

Comment: Okay, here's another problem, I don't use jQuery... Is it possible?

Comment: Ah, thanks! Unfortunately I can't mark multiple answers as correct.

Answer (score 4):

I maintain some IE11 "compatibility mode" pages which run like IE7, and the pure javascript solution above did **not** work for me. The first opening option tag would inexplicably be stripped using a direct innerHTML assignment.

What worked for me was explicitly appending each option in the select's option collection to the new select. In this instance it was to support an AJAX call, so I cleared the list first, but I'm sure this could append as well.

```
var fromSelect = document.getElementById('a');
var toSelect = document.getElementById('b');
toSelect.innerHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < fromSelect.options.length; i++) {
    var option = fromSelect.options[i];
    toSelect.appendChild(option);
}
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else who is stuck in compatibility mode, since this page was at the top of the list in a Google search.

Answer (score 2):

use jQuery foreach?

```
$("#the-id option").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var txt = $(this).html();
    $("the-other-id").append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(txt);
    );
});
```

Comment: Man, I hate loop... Is there any way I can do this without a loop? Also, I don't use jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

you can do that easily via [jquery:](http://jsfiddle.net/e7zeu/)

```
<select id="sel1">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>

<select id="sel2">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sel2").html($("#sel1").html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cloneBtn').click(function() {
    var $options = $("#myselect > option").clone();
    $('#second').empty();
    $('#second').append($options);
    $('#second').val($('#myselect').val());
});

 This is used to copy the value and the innerHTML. Its better to copy the key,
 value and the OPTIONS.i.e. the selected value and the options.
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an older thread but I hope the following helps someone. No loops at all.

```
function copyFromMultiselect(srcId,targetId, allFlag){
    if(allFlag){
        $("#"+targetId).append($("#"+srcId).html());
        $("#"+srcId).empty();
    }else{
        $("#"+targetId).append($("#"+tabContentId+" #"+srcId+" option:selected"));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    //first ans can be modified as follows to get direct result while using dropdown
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    onload
    function myFunction1(){     
    var first = document.getElementById('selector_a');
    var second = document.getElementById('selector_b');
    var chk=document.getElementById('selector_main').value;
        if(chk == "1")
        var options = first.innerHTML;
        else
        var options = second.innerHTML;
    var out = document.getElementById('selector_c');
    out.innerHTML = options;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="myFunction1()">
    <select id="selector_main" onchange="myFunction1()">
    <option value="none" disabled>--choose--</option>
    <option value="1">option_A</option>
    <option value="2">option_B</option>
    </select>
    <select id="selector_a" hidden>
    <option value="none" disabled>--select--</option>
    <option>op1</option>
    <option>op 2</option>
    </select>

    <select id="selector_b" hidden>
    <option value="none" disabled>--select--</option>
    <option>op 3</option>
    <option>op 4</option>
    </select>
    <select id="selector_c">
    <option>--select col1 first--</option>   
    </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: A code-only answer with no description is not recommended